# In C#, if A implements IX and B inherits from A , does it necessarily follow that B implements IX?

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, interface, liskov-substitution-principle

In C#, if A implements IX and B inherits from A , does it necessarily follow that B implements IX? if yes is it because of LSP ? are there any differences between :

1.

```
Interface IX;
Class A : IX;
Class B : A;
```

and

2.

```
Interface IX;
Class A : IX;
Class B : A, IX;
```

?

Is there a terminology associated with B implementing IX though the chain of inheritance or B implementing IX directly?

PS: I am Assuming in both cases the interface is implemented implicitly, not explicitly. Any Patterns that utilize on 1 and would not work if they were implemented as in 2?

Comment: There is no difference (for non-explicit interfaces). By LSP subtyping B must be able to 'replace' A; and thus everything A implements. ReSharper (and maybe VS these days) will warn about a redundant interface specification (B:IX) in case #2.

Comment: @user2864740 Even if in 2 B implements IX differently than A?

Comment: The 'semantic' strictness of LSP is not captured in the type system; and arguably the implementation for B (for some B) *must* be different than A (for some A) or else subtype polymorphism would be useless.

Comment: Logically, it wouldn't be possible to have class `A` implement `IX`, and have class `B` not, as class `B` inherits the implementation of `A`.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa664593(v=VS.71).aspx):

> A class inherits all interface implementations provided by its base classes.
>   Without explicitly re-implementing an interface, a derived class cannot in any way alter the interface mappings it inherits from its base classes.

However,  it goes on to say that if the base class implements the interface method as virtual, it can be overridden by the derived class.  So the implicit implementation can be overridden in a derived class explicitly.

Comment: so does that mean the subclass can be explicitly be casted to any of implemented interfaces in it's base class?

Comment: @Arjang Yes, interfaces define methods and properties that a class **must** implement.  Take some class `Person`, implementing `INameParts`.  Assume `INameParts` has two properties, `FirstName` and `LastName`.  This just means that the `Person` class has two public properties `FirstName` and `LastName`.  If you subclassed `Person` as `Man`, a instance of `Man` would have the same public properties as `Person`, which would include the implementation of `INameParts`.  The getter for `Man.FirstName` **could differ from** `Person.FirstName`, but they both have the `FirstName` property. Make sense?

Comment: yes, just wanted to make sure that implicit implementation will still be accessible explicitly.